# How can i have folder in sublime text2 sidebar ?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I recently have started to write code in sublime text 2 editor.
I can have my opened file in sidebar but i want to have folder in sidebar too. How can i add folder to my sidebar?

Comment: While you are composing your question, a list entitled **Questions that may already have your answer** shows up with potentially relevant questions. **Use that list** and open up the suggested questions in new tabs. In this case, the **very first** question in that list had your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]To open a project or a folder

- In your menu bar got to File.
- In sub menu Open Folder.

file > open folder

Comment: I hope this answer is helpful?

Comment: Lawani i want to have folder in my sidebar !! and can access to folders i use a lot .

Comment: I have updated my answer with a the picture.

Comment: hello again . i suddenly understand that after open folder you can put it in your sidebar by drag and drop ! sorry that my reputation is not enough to like your answer!

Answer (score 0):

i finally find out how to do it!
1- view -> show sidebar . 
2- file -> open folder
3- drag the folder you want to the sidebar and drop it !

Comment: As explained to you by Harish Lalwani you do **not** need to drag the folder. You can simply open the folder of interest the same way you open a file of interest.

Comment: Just realised that you may have the unstated desire to have the folder you are opening added to the sidebar you currently have open. In that case add the folder to the current project by using the relevant command in the `Project` menu.